# Tab Bar disappearing when switching views

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I was hoping that you could help me with a small issue.

I have a program that has a tab bar controller with 5 tab bar items. On the main page this tab bar appears and I can switch between the 5 tab bar items with no issues.

On some views I have a button which loads a xib file, some of which are xibs that are selectable from the tab bar. However, whenever I load a view using a button I lose the tab bar - and this is my issue.

My current way of loading between views is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)newGamePressed 
{
    NewGameIntro *screen = [[NewGameIntro alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
}
```

This is probably quite an obvious solution but I am pretty new to Objective-C and searching the forum I couldn't find anything particularly obvious.

Any help that anyone can give would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

PS The way I loaded the TabBarController was as follows (if this helps) in the delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TabBarController" owner:self options:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting a modal view which will cover the entire window as it is designed to. If your goal is to simply push a new controller onto the stack you will need your tab's root views to be a UINavigationController upon which you will simply push another view using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:...]
```